# interrupting a class that is already in use by another class . . 

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i am trying to understand somthing strange.
i wanted to call from regular class to cocos2d class.
the cocos2d class name is HelloWorldScene , but when i call it , i was told use only HelloWorld , without the scene like this :

```
HelloWorld *ran=[[HelloWorld alloc] init];
    [ran HardwareEvent:DollPart];
```

why not scene ??
whats happen is that the cocos class is been called, and also the init is being called, and if i am trying to play animation it doesnt played.(but being called)

I HAVE to say that the cocos class is the first one being called when the app begins, and later other regular class is interrupt it again by the code i wrote here.

so whats wrong ?
how can i interrupt a class that is already in use, by another class ?
why animation is not working? is it somthing to do with layers ?

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's not the way the Cocos2D libraries work.  If you are as new to Cocos2D as it seems you are then I recommend:

[Ray Wenderlich.com (tutorials for Cocos2D and other iOS subjects)](http://www.raywenderlich.com)

HelloWorldScene should be the scene that runs by default with a new template Cocos2D project.  If you want to call a method in the HelloWorldLayer class you just call [self methodName];

Comment: thats not true. as the people from cocos2d told me  [self methodName]; is not ok . you have to do : [(HelloWorld*)[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] getChildByTag:42] HardwareEvent:DollPart];

Comment: Yeah I read that on your duplicate question lol. Guess I misunderstood.